# Merge by row index and column label

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, merge

```
> df1
   x  y
1 13  7
2 14  8
4 16 10
5 17 11
6 18 12


> df2
  index_df1 y
1         2 a
2         4 d
3         5 e
4         6 f
```

How can I merge `df1` with `df2`, with the index of `df1` and the column `"index_df1"` of `df2`. Like:

```
z <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = 0, by.y = "index_df1", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: Add rownames as column, then merge as usual, link provided by @CPak above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::left_join` to merge two data.frames as:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("rn" = "index_df1")) %>%
  select(-rn)

#    x y.x  y.y
# 1 13   7 <NA>
# 2 14   8    a
# 3 15   9 <NA>
# 4 16  10    d
# 5 17  11    e
# 6 18  12    f
```

**Updated:** Based on feedback from OP. If rows are not sequential in `df1` then an option could be as:

```
# Use `index_df1` to add a column having value of x in df1
df2$x <- df1[df2$index_df1,"x"]

# Now, merge
merge(df1, df2[,c("y", "x")], by.x = "x", by.y = "x", all.x = TRUE)
#    x y.x  y.y
# 1 13   7 <NA>
# 2 14   8    a
# 3 15   9 <NA>
# 4 16  10    d
# 5 17  11    e
# 6 18  12    f
```

Comment: I forgot to add that the index in df1 is not continuous, as I deleted some rows on it.

Comment: Why are we using full_join?

Comment: @zx8754 Good point. I should have used `left_join` as OP intended you use `all.x = TRUE`

Comment: @Chris Then you can add a column in `df2` as `df2$x <- df1[df2$index_df1,"x"]` and then merge `df1` and `df2`